# What kind of datatypes should I use for the return value of a Web API method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API controller that returns data to my client. The code looks like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("Retrieve")]
    public IEnumerable<Reference> Retrieve(int subjectId)
    {
        return _referenceService.Retrieve(subjectId);
    }
```

Can someone tell me is it necessary to specify the ActionName?

Also should I return an IEnumerable, an IList or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe if your ASP.NET routing is setup correctly you don't need to specify the `ActionName`, for example:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute("0", "{controller}/{action}/{arg1}");
}
```

Will match `/YourControllerName/Retrieve/132`

What you return is based entirely on your media-type formatters, of which the default is `XmlFormatter` and `JsonFormatter`.  These can be found in `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters` and will be chosen based on the `Accept` header provided by the client.

We, for example, use [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) for our response formatting, configured by:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute("0", "{controller}/{action}/{arg1}");

    MediaTypeFormatterCollection formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;
    formatters.Remove(formatters.XmlFormatter);

    var jsonFormatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
    jsonFormatter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    jsonFormatter.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
}
```

This tells WebApi to disallow any XML formatting and only return JSON using the provided JSON.Net contract resolver.  JSON.Net supports serializing `IEnumerable`.

I would, however, recommend returning a `HttpResponseMessage` instead.  This allows you to set the status code as well (This still uses the media type formatter, it's just a cleaner wrapper).  You can use this like so:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Retrieve(int subjectId)
{
    var response _referenceService.Retrieve(subjectId);

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will do it the way you suggested. How about if nothing is returned from the retrieve. Is there a way I can handle that?

Comment: I just run a test serializing an empty collection (eg: `IEnumerable<Reference> references = new List<Reference>();`); Json.Net serializes an empty collection as an empty array (eg: `[]`).

Answer (score 1):

You should return HttpStatusCode instead of data if have not requirement, like POST method should return OK or whatever.
or if want record like Get method should return type of record.

also you no need to add attribute on method like Get,Put,Delete etc because webapi automatically detect method according to action like if you are getting data then your method name should be start with Get  like GetEmployee etc.